# Changing image contrast with GDI+ and C#

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+, screen, contrast

My problem is the following :

I am making a program, which can manipulate brightness, gamma and contrast through C# code. For brightness and gamma it is OK. I have achieved it through code I found in the net, but I can't for contrast.

The only thing I have found by now is a `CalculateRamp` method, which has as input parameters `(double level, double brightness, double gamma, double contrast)`. I know what input to give for brightness, gamma and contrast (the values from the sliders in the interface), but I don't know what level is for.

The other problem with this method is that when I pass the calculated ramp with random `level` parameter as a parameter to `SetDeviceGammaRamp(IntPtr hDC,ref RAMP rmp)` it actually changes the screen contrast, but when I move the brightness slider the changes made from the contrast slider are lost. It may be because of using the same method or I am not sure for what.

I will be very thankful to any help or ideas, no matter if they are changes to my current solution which is not full, or a brand new solution - which I would prefer - because I feel in some way unsure with this. Thanks in advance to everybody.

Here is the code of the `CalculateRamp` method, as the function `SetDeviceGammaRamp(...)` is called by me to manipulate the contrast with the current calculated ramp. I am not sure if I have to use it in this way or not:

```
public static void CalculateRamp(double level, double gamma, double brightness, double contrast)
{
    ramp.Red = new ushort[256];
    ramp.Green = new ushort[256];
    ramp.Blue = new ushort[256];

    gamma /= 10;
    brightness = 1 + (((brightness - 50) / 100) * 65535);
    contrast = 1 + ((contrast - 50) / 100);
    level = 1 + ((level - 50) / 100);

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        double value = i * 256;
        value = (Math.Pow(value / 65535, 1 / gamma) * 65535) + 0.5;
        value = ((((value / 65535) - 0.5) * contrast) + 0.5) * 65535;
        value = value += brightness;
        value *= level;
        ramp.Red[i] = ramp.Green[i] = ramp.Blue[i] = (ushort)Math.Min((double)65535, Math.Max((double)0, value));
    }
    SetDeviceGammaRamp(GetDC(IntPtr.Zero), ref ramp);
}
```