# Reference CalculateRamp - How to derive entry arguments from the existing Gamma Ramp - My best solution

Tags: c#, c++

In reference to the widely used CalculateRamp code at:
[Changing image contrast with GDI+ and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773344/changing-image-contrast-with-gdi-and-c-sharp)

```
    public static void CalculateRamp(double level, double gamma, double brightness, double contrast)
    {
        ramp.Red = new ushort[256];
        ramp.Green = new ushort[256];
        ramp.Blue = new ushort[256];

        gamma /= 10;
        brightness = 1 + (((brightness - 50) / 100) * 65535);
        contrast = 1 + ((contrast - 50) / 100);
        level = 1 + ((level - 50) / 100);

        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        {
            double value = i * 256;
            value = (Math.Pow(value / 65535, 1 / gamma) * 65535) + 0.5;
            value = ((((value / 65535) - 0.5) * contrast) + 0.5) * 65535;
            value = value += brightness;
            value *= level;
            ramp.Red[i] = ramp.Green[i] = ramp.Blue[i] = (ushort)Math.Min((double)65535, Math.Max((double)0, value));
        }
        SetDeviceGammaRamp(GetDC(IntPtr.Zero), ref ramp);
    }
```

How would you calculate the input values (arguments) for this method directly from the existing Gamma Ramp? In other words, what would be the reverse method?

If I am going to provide these utilities to the user, I need to present them with their current settings prior to their making the adjustments.

I have tried for three days to come up with a solution, and must admit that this is beyond my capabilities.

Update Sept 8, 2016 - My best solution...

While I worked long and hard looking for a mathematical solution, I finally went back and played around with the iteration method.

A blunt force iteration that calculates each and every possible setting and then checks for a match will run for more than 20 minutes; which is unacceptable.

I found that I could take a single sample point in the middle of the array and quickly iterate through all possible settings to find a match for that one sample; and then perform all 256 of the calculations for the array to see if we had a complete match. This operation generally runs in less than a second.

But I realized that there was yet another problem. If the Gamma Ramp was not programmed using the CalculateRamp algorithm (such as factory setting) then it is unlikely that we will find an exact match for our settings; and our solution will fail.

So I devised a backup plan that uses four sample points from across the gamma ramp array; and then set up a "span" of acceptable values that would provide a close approximation for our settings. The criteria for "span" would broaden after each failure, and re-enter the search. This scenario will produce an approximation of the Gamma Ramp Settings usually within about three seconds. This is acceptable since my main program can perform this operation during the program startup sequence.

Here is my C++ solution...

```
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    int __fastcall TForm1::Round( double flt ){
       int num = (int) flt;
       if( flt >= 0 ){
          if( flt - num >= .5 ){ num++;}
       }else{
          if( flt - num <= -.5 ){ num--;}
       }
       return( num );
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void __fastcall TForm1::GetGammaRampSettings(void){
       // level should be between 2 and 100
       // gamma should be between 2 and 50
       // brigntess should be between 0 and 100
       // contrast should be between 0 and 100

       double i,j,k,m;
       double gamma,bright,cntrst,level;
       double v1,v2,v3,v4;
       double c1,c2,c3,c4;
       double a1,a2,a3,a4,b1,b2,b3,b4; //for best estimate criteria
       int x1,x2,x3,x4,x5;
       int d,n;
       WORD span = 8;
       bool tog = false;

       TDateTime strt, end;

       WORD GammaArray[3][256]; //Gamma Ramp Array buffer
       WORD CompArray[256];     //Array buffer for comparison

       HDC GammaDC = GetDC( NULL );  //fetch the gamma ramp array
       GetDeviceGammaRamp( GammaDC, GammaArray );
       ReleaseDC( NULL, GammaDC );

       strt=Now();

       //Find two endpoints for the GammaArray
       for( x1 = 0; x1 < 256; x1++ ){
          if( GammaArray[0][x1] > 0 ){ break;}
       }

       for( x2 = 0; x2 < 256; x2++ ){
          if( GammaArray[0][x2] == 65535 ){ break;}
       }
       if( x2 == 256 ){ x2 = 255; }

       x5 = x1 + Round( (double)( x2 - x1 ) / 2.0 );

       Memo1->Lines->Add( "x1 = " + IntToStr( x1 )); //start
       Memo1->Lines->Add( "x2 = " + IntToStr( x2 )); //end
       Memo1->Lines->Add( "x5 = " + IntToStr( x5 )); //mid

       //neutral settings are as follows...
       //Bright = 50
       //Contrast = 50
       //Level = 50
       //Gamma = 10

       //The following code will look for an exact match to the settings
       //but it may fail if the gamma ramp was not programmed using the
       //original CalculateRamp code. ie: A factory setting, or other

       for(n=0;n<=40;){//gamma
          if( n < 9 ){         //gamma begins with a neutral setting of 10 and
             if( tog ){        //then increments high and low depending on tog
                i = ( 10 - n );
                tog = false; n++;
                if( i == 10 ){ continue;}
             }else{
                i = ( 10 + n );
                tog = true;
             }
          }else{
             i = ( 10 + n++ );
          }
          gamma = i / 10;
          v1 = ( pow( (double)(x5 * 256) / 65535, 1 / gamma) * 65535) + 0.5;
          for( j = 2; j < 101 ; j++ ){//level    //980,000 possible iterations
             level = 1 + ((j - 50) / 100);
             for( k = 0; k < 101; k++ ){//bright
                bright = 1 + (((k - 50) / 100) * 65535);
                for( m = 0; m < 101; m++ ){//contrast
                   cntrst = 1 + ((m - 50) / 100);
                   //Test only the mid-line value at first
                   //To see if a complete comparison is warranted
                   c1 = (((( v1 / 65535 ) - 0.5) * cntrst) + 0.5) * 65535;
                   c1 = c1 += bright;
                   c1 *= level;
                   if( c1 > 65535){ c1 = 65535; }
                   if( c1 < 0 ){ c1 = 0; }
             if( (WORD) c1 == GammaArray[0][x5] ){
                      for( d = 0; d < 256; d++ ){
                         c1 = ( pow( (double)(d * 256) / 65535, 1 / gamma) * 65535) + 0.5;
                         c1 = ((( (c1 / 65535) - 0.5) * cntrst) + 0.5) * 65535;
                         c1 = c1 += bright;
                         c1 *= level;
                         if( c1 > 65535 ){ c1 = 65535;}
                         if( c1 < 0 ){ c1 = 0;}
                         CompArray[d] = (WORD) c1;
                      }
                      if(memcmp( &CompArray[0], &GammaArray[0][0], 2*256) == 0){
                         goto ENDIT;
                      }
                   }
                }
             }
          }
       }

       //Since an exact match could not be found for the current
       //gamma ramp settings, we will broaden our criteria and
       //search for the best match for our gamma ramp settings.

       //Here our search is based on the start and end values,
       //plus two additional values that are 1/4 of the overall distance
       //above the start point; and 1/4 the distance below the end point.

       Memo1->Lines->Add("Values NOT Discovered!!!");
       Memo1->Lines->Add("Widening the Search....");

       x3 = x1 + Round( (double)( x2 - x1 ) / 4.0 );
       x4 = x1 + Round(( (double)( x2 - x1 ) / 4.0 )*3);

       Memo1->Lines->Add( "x1 = " + IntToStr( x1 )); //start
       Memo1->Lines->Add( "x2 = " + IntToStr( x2 )); //end
       Memo1->Lines->Add( "x3 = " + IntToStr( x3 )); // 1/4
       Memo1->Lines->Add( "x4 = " + IntToStr( x4 )); // 3/4

       BROADEN:

       a1 = GammaArray[0][x1]+span; //these are our high and low
       b1 = GammaArray[0][x1]-span; //values that the ramp values must
                                    //fall within to be accepted
       a2 = GammaArray[0][x2]+span;
       b2 = GammaArray[0][x2]-span; //span begins at 8 and increments upwards
                                    //with each loop, ever widening the
       a3 = GammaArray[0][x3]+span; //the search criteria
       b3 = GammaArray[0][x3]-span;

       a4 = GammaArray[0][x4]+span;
       b4 = GammaArray[0][x4]-span;

       tog=false;
       for(n=0;n<=40;){//gamma
          if( n < 9 ){         //gamma begins with a neutral setting of 10 and
             if( tog ){        //then increments high and low depending on tog
                i = ( 10 - n );
                tog = false; n++;
                if( i == 10 ){ continue;} //prevents two instances of i == 10
             }else{
                i = ( 10 + n );
                tog = true;
             }
          }else{
             i = ( 10 + n++ );
          }
          gamma = i / 10;
          v1 = ( pow( (double)(x1 * 256) / 65535, 1 / gamma) * 65535) + 0.5;
          v2 = ( pow( (double)(x2 * 256) / 65535, 1 / gamma) * 65535) + 0.5;
          v3 = ( pow( (double)(x3 * 256) / 65535, 1 / gamma) * 65535) + 0.5;
          v4 = ( pow( (double)(x4 * 256) / 65535, 1 / gamma) * 65535) + 0.5;
          for( j = 2; j < 101 ; j++ ){//level    //980,000 possible iterations
             level = 1 + ((j - 50) / 100);
             for( k = 0; k < 101; k++ ){//bright
                bright = 1 + (((k - 50) / 100) * 65535);
                for( m = 0; m < 101; m++ ){//contrast
                   cntrst = 1 + ((m - 50) / 100);
                   //Test the four sample values to see if the
                   //results falls within our acceptance criteria.
                   c1 = (((( v1 / 65535 ) - 0.5) * cntrst) + 0.5) * 65535;
                   c1 = c1 += bright;
                   c1 *= level;
                   c2 = (((( v2 / 65535 ) - 0.5) * cntrst) + 0.5) * 65535;
                   c2 = c2 += bright;
                   c2 *= level;
                   c3 = (((( v3 / 65535 ) - 0.5) * cntrst) + 0.5) * 65535;
                   c3 = c3 += bright;
                   c3 *= level;
                   c4 = (((( v4 / 65535 ) - 0.5) * cntrst) + 0.5) * 65535;
                   c4 = c4 += bright;
                   c4 *= level;
             if( c1 <= a1 && c1 >= b1 &&  c2 <= a2 && c2 >= b2 &&
                       c3 <= a3 && c3 >= b3 &&  c4 <= a4 && c4 >= b4 ){
                       Memo1->Lines->Add("Best Estimate +/- " + IntToStr( span ));
                       goto ENDIT;
                   }
                }
             }
          }
       }

       if( span < 256){
          span *= 2;
          goto BROADEN;
       }else if( span <= 4096 ){ //set the maximum allowance for "span"
          span += 128;           //which is the basis for the allowable
          goto BROADEN;          //search criteria
       }

       //if we get to this point then we have utterly failed.
       Memo1->Lines->Add("Values STILL NOT Discovered.");
       Memo1->Lines->Add("GetGammaRampSettings Failed.");
       return;

       ENDIT:
       end=Now();
       Memo1->Lines->Add("Execution duration was "+
             FormatDateTime("nn:ss:zzz",end-strt));

       //Report on findings...
       Memo1->Lines->Add("Bright = " + IntToStr( (int) k ));
       Memo1->Lines->Add("Cntrst = " + IntToStr( (int) m ));
       Memo1->Lines->Add("Level = " + IntToStr( (int) j ));
       Memo1->Lines->Add("Gamma = " + IntToStr( (int) i ));

    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Just for clarity, given ramp you want to work out gamma, contrast, brightness and level?

Comment: That is exactly correct. I'm trying to work the problem backwards from the GetDeviceGammaRamp function call to whatever input values would be required to create the current gamma ramp array: What will be the Brightness setting, what will be the Contrast setting, what will be the Level setting, and what will be the Gamma setting "going in".